# sessions id keeps changing on every page refresh or change

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

im having an issue with sessions, my sessions are not persistent because the session id keeps changing every time i refresh or change the page.

i've tried adding an dummy session (ze) after the session start to prevent it but the session id keeps changing, weirdly enough, it works fine and doesn't change on chrome, this issue only happens with the other browsers.

the session_save_path() is writable, i tested with

```
if ( !is_writable(session_save_path()) ) {
   echo 'Session save path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable!'; 
}
```

my server isn't local and the php version is 5.3.5

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["ze"] = "lalal";
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you have cookies disabled in the other browsers you are testing with. Try using Firebug (FF) or Developer Tools (IE) to verify the cookie is being set and sent to the server correctly.

Comment: i dont, i asked a friend to test and he has the same issues, it works on chrome but not the others, it's really weird

Comment: I still believe the first place to look is the cookies. Try dumping the contents of the cookie array (`var_dump($_COOKIE)`) to see if there is a difference in the cookies your server is getting back from the different types of browsers.

Comment: i added var_dump($_COOKIE), nothing different

<?php 
echo session_id().' <br/ >';
?>

keeps showing an different id when refreshing on all browsers except chrome

Comment: Have a check in thr browser or the cookie is actually set. In firefox you can check this under richt click > page-info > security > cookies